# NoSuchMethodError: 'The getter 'uid' was called on null' in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to flutter. And I am getting this NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null. I have red many posts and it seems like I need to use await with async. But I have no Idea how I can do it. This is happening when I want to pass the current uid of the user.
Here is my code:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  //final String userProfileId;
  //ProfilePage({this.userProfileId});
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {

  FirebaseUser thecurrentuser;
  profilepicture() {

    return FutureBuilder(

        future: userReference.document(thecurrentuser.uid).get(), // So here I am getting the error
        builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
        User user = User.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);
          if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
            return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
    }
          User user = User.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 45.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Mahesh_Babu_in_Spyder_%28cropped%29.jpg')),
                Text(user.username),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 1, child: Column(children: <Widget>[Text("coolbro")]))
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

My user model

```
class User{
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String username;

  User({
    this.uid,
    this.email,
    this.username,
  });

  factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return User(
      uid: doc['uid'],
      email: doc['email'],
      username: doc['username']    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing `currentUser` that's why it is equal to null. You should do the following:

```
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return userReference.document(firebaseUser.uid).get();
  }
```

So create a method that returns a `Future<DocumentSnapshot>` and inside that document you can retrieve the current user and use `get()` to retrieve the data.

Then inside the `FutureBuilder`, do the following:

```
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
```

---

```
      if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
        return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
}
 else if(dataSnapshot.hasData){
      User user = User.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
                radius: 45.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Mahesh_Babu_in_Spyder_%28cropped%29.jpg')),
            Text(user.username),
            Expanded(
                flex: 1, child: Column(children: <Widget>[Text("coolbro")]))
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. But this time I am getting the error . The method [] was called on null.

Comment: Try `if(dataSnapshot.hasData){ User user = User.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);` inside the FutureBuilder

Comment: I have edited my profilepicture(). Should I had the if statement you suggested under my (if !dataSnapshot.hasData)

Comment: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#89c6e):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("uid")

The relevant error-causing widget was :When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod 
#1      DocumentSnapshot.[] 

#2      new User.fromDocument 

#3      _ProfilePageState.profilepicture.<anonymous closure> 

#4      _FutureBuilderState.build 

...

Comment: I haved added the full error. Seems like the error is coming from the new method

Comment: @LalliGarden the error is from this`User.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data)`, why didn't you add the code I gave you in the comment? You get this error because data is still not retrieved yet

Comment: But I didn't  know where to add it

Comment: Oh wait. I did add it to my code. I just forgot to add it in the edit. Sorry.

Comment: No still getting the error. I even tried flutter clean. But the when I wrote print(datasnapShot.data) : I get instance of DocumentSnapshot. And then when I wrote print(datasnapShot.data.data): I get null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215216/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-lalli-garden).

Comment: Could use please come once to the chat room. I have only one question while debugging

Comment: Works for me! Future<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return userRef.doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();
  }